# Lucene 3.5 is not supporting Chinese Russain Korean Languages while searching

Tags: java, lucene

I am using Lucene 3.5 Standard Analyzer for indexing and searching. Its working for all languages other than Chinese, Japanese and Korean languages. I tried with CJK Analyzer and Chinese Analyzers. But still not working. Index is getting created correctly. We have verified this with Luke tool. But not able to search the above language words, both using Luke tool and from code using Analyzers. Any solution for this.

```
伊拉克航空公司               

+name:伊拉克航空公司~0.9     This  is the lucene query generated by the analyzer for this chinese word. But not returning result. But other languages and its corresponding query is returning results
```

Comment: are you using any analyzer during query time ? show some examples of our index and query strings.

Comment: edited the question with example

Answer (score 2):

For Chinese, there are many useful 3rd party **Analyzer** such as:

1. mmseg4j
2. [IK-analyzer](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ik-analyzer/)
3. ansj_seg
4. imdict-chinese-analyzer

I recommend IK-analyzer, for example:
Add this to your dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.janeluo</groupId>
        <artifactId>ikanalyzer</artifactId>
        <version>2012_u6</version>
    </dependency>
```

The example code:

```
public class LuenceFirst {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Analyzer analyzer = new IKAnalyzer(); 
        TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream("", "伊拉克航空公司");

        CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute = tokenStream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        OffsetAttribute offsetAttribute = tokenStream.addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);
        tokenStream.reset();
        while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
            System.out.println("start→" + offsetAttribute.startOffset());
            System.out.println(charTermAttribute);
            System.out.println("end→" + offsetAttribute.endOffset()); 
        }
        tokenStream.close();
    }
}
```

The output is:
    start→0

```
伊拉克

end→3

start→3

航空公司

end→7

start→3

航空

end→5

start→5

公司

end→7
```

For Japanese:

1. [koromoji](http://www.atilika.org/)
2. [lucene-gosen](http://code.google.com/p/lucene-gosen/)

Comment: Thanks for the update.....                                                                                                    public abstract TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName,
                                        Reader reader)                                                               The second argument of method tokenStream is Reader right? I am getting a compilation error here when I copied your code

Comment: @vishnu, which version are you using. Please remove any libraries related to the Lucence and use the dependency of ik only. Ik has contained lucence libs

Comment: ikanalyzer-2012_u6 is dependend on lucene-core 4.7.2. Here we are using lucene 3.5. That may be the problem

Comment: Are you sure without using 3rd party Analyzers  we can't search Chinese characters ? lucense upgradation from 3.5 is time consuming becuase there is vast code difference in its implementation. With 3.5 lucene itself, is there is any other way to support these characters?